# Node js save local storage images to server

Tags: javascript, node.js, local-storage

I have a function in Node that I have written to save my local storage images to a local file on my server, It seems to work fine on my local but now I have uploaded to the server I seem to keep getting errors.

In my console I get some console logs I have added to help me debug, So far my console reads :

> request in
>
> test 1 function started
>
> test 1 function ended
>
> save photo function base64 start
>
> save photo function start if else
>
> error saving photo

no matter what I change I keep getting the `error saving photo`

Can anyone see In my code why I keep getting this error? any help is much appreciated I have been at this error for hours now.

**Full code**

```
app.post('/mm3/back-end/savePhoto', function (req, res) {
    console.log('test 1 function started');
    var folder = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 20);
    var photos = req.body;
    var counts = 0;
    console.log('test 1 function ended');

    var callback = function(counts){
        console.log('start if else');
        if(counts < photos.length){
            saveBase64(photos[counts],folder,counts,callback);
            console.log('test if line');
        }else{
            var counts = 0;
            var response = {"folder":folder, "photos": photos.length};
            console.log('test else line');
            res.send(response)
        }
        console.log('end of function');
    };
    saveBase64(photos[counts],folder,counts,callback);
});

app.post('/mm3/downloadZip', function(req, res){
    console.log('test zip file started');
    var photos = req.body;
    var out =  photos[0];
    var test = out.split('/');
    var loc  = test.pop();
    var end =  test.join('/');
    console.log('test 3 function Generate zip file');
    console.log(end);
    var outName = '/' + end +'/mm3/MockUp.zip';
    var output = fs.createWriteStream(outName);
    var archive = archiver('zip', {store: true });
    var zip = function(photos, f){
        for(var t = 0; t < photos.length; t++){
            var file = 'mockUp'+ t +'.jpg';
            var from = '/var/www/html' +  photos[t];
            archive.file( from, { name: file });
        }
        f();
    };

    output.on('close', function() {
        var photos = req.body;
        var out =  photos[0];
        var test = out.split('/');
        var loc  = test.pop();
        var end =  test.join('/');
        res.send(end + '/MockUp.zip');
        console.log('archiver has been finalized and the output file descriptor has closed.');
    });
    archive.on('error', function(err) {
        throw err;
    });

    archive.pipe(output);
    zip(photos, f);
    function f(){
        archive.finalize();
    }
});

function saveBase64(photo,folder, counts, callback){
    console.log('save photo function base64 start');
    var result = photo.split(',')[1];
    var path = '/mm3/tmp/' + folder;
    var filename = path + "/out"+ counts + ".png";
    mkdirp( path, function() {

        fs.writeFile(filename, result, 'base64', function(error){
            console.log('save photo function start if else');
            if (error) {
                console.log('error saving photo');
            }else{
                console.log('photo saved');
                counts ++;
                callback(counts);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

UPDATE:

am now getting

> Error: request entity too large
>       at readStream (/var/www/html/mm3/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:196:17)
>       at getRawBody (/var/www/html/mm3/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:106:12)
>       at read (/var/www/html/mm3/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:76:3)
>       at Layer.jsonParser [as handle] (/var/www/html/mm3/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:127:5)
>       at trim_prefix (/var/www/html/mm3/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:226:17)
>       at /var/www/html/mm3/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:198:9
>       at Function.proto.process_params (/var/www/html/mm3/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:251:12)
>       at next (/var/www/html/mm3/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:189:19)
>       at Layer.expressInit [as handle] (/var/www/html/mm3/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:23:5)
>       at trim_prefix (/var/www/html/mm3/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:226:17)
>       at /var/www/html/mm3/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:198:9
>       at Function.proto.process_params (/var/www/html/mm3/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:251:12)
>       at next (/var/www/html/mm3/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:189:19)
>       at Layer.query [as handle] (/var/www/html/mm3/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/query.js:37:5)
>       at trim_prefix (/var/www/html/mm3/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:226:17)
>       at /var/www/html/mm3/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:198:9
>       at Function.proto.process_params (/var/www/html/mm3/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:251:12)
>       at next (/var/www/html/mm3/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:189:19)
>       at Function.proto.handle (/var/www/html/mm3/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:234:5)
>       at Function.app.handle (/var/www/html/mm3/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:119:16)
>       at Server.app (/var/www/html/mm3/node_modules/express/lib/express.js:28:9)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)

Comment: Have you tried to look at what error? (substitute `console.log('error saving photo');` with `console.log(error);`

Comment: Hmm ill look into it now

Comment: Why not just use [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer)?

Comment: because i did not know about it lol, so how much of my current code would need to change ?

Comment: @user2314737 good point, its helped me find the error `error saving photo
{ [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/mm3/tmp/im0u                         ye8xzdunmi/out0.png']
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/mm3/tmp/im0uye8xzdunmi/out0.png' }
`